# Nested Divs Malfunctioning in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So i have nested divs in chrome

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
   <div id="content">
   </div>
</div>
```

The wrapper div is just a bordered container in the shape of a box. On safari/firefox the content resides inside of the box and 50% of chrome the content div resides in the box however the other 50% of the time it is outside of the box. I don't really know what to do as it works in Safari and firefox and for some reason is a toss up in chrome. Could it just my computer? Has anyone experienced this problem?

Thanks

```
#wrapper{
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 5%;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 90%;
   background-color: #efefef;
}

#content{
   height:78px;
   width:100%;
   border-bottom:solid 1px gray;
   font-weight:1000;
   margin-left:0px !important;
   background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: Please post your CSS. It sounds like a positioning problem. Some more details will help us.

Comment: It'll help if you posted the css for both containers, as of now content should be wrapped in wrapper at all times

Comment: hopefully that helps

Comment: What do you mean by "outside the box"? Below it? Above it? beside it? by how much? can you get a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `box-sizing: border-box;` on the `#wrapper`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: absolute;` it removes the element from the natural element flow on the page. If you're able to, you should remove the absolute position.

Keep in mind that if you want to use height percentages, you will need to define the top level element to be 100%.

```
body,html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Body and HTML will inherit from Window. Then all other elements on the page will inherit from body or html.

Here's the full:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#content{
    height:78px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:solid 1px gray;
    font-weight:1000;
    margin-left:0px !important;
    background-color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twqxoc0j/

> The trade-off, and most important thing to remember, about absolute
>   positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of
>   elements on the page. An element with this type of positioning is not
>   affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. This
>   is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute
>   positioning. It's overuse or improper use can limit the flexibility of
>   your site.

From: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/